# I want to move to next screen after getting response from twitter login

Tags: objective-c, xcode

not able to to move to next screen as soon as I get response from twitter login.

```
 [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    if (session) {
        NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
        NSString *userStr = [session userName];
        NSString *userStr1 = [session userID];
        UIStoryboard *strory = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        phoneViewController *editobj = [strory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"phoneViewController"];

        [self presentViewController:editobj animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    UIStoryboard *strory = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    phoneViewController *editobj = [strory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"phoneViewController"];

    [self presentViewController:editobj animated:YES completion:nil];

}];
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you do some debug by yourself? Is `strory` a valid value? Is `phoneViewController ` a valid value? Are you in the main queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should execute all interface-related tasks **only in the main queue**. So simply dispatch your view controllers transition to it:

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    if (session) {
        NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
        NSString *userStr = [session userName];
        NSString *userStr1 = [session userID];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIStoryboard *strory = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

            phoneViewController *editobj = [strory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"phoneViewController"];

            [self presentViewController:editobj animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```